# An Unnatural Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Try find the answer to this puzzle below. I'm looking for two words.

---

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The numbers in the circles

> span from 1 to 118, a rather convenient range for converting letters to numbers. The diagram at the top sure seems to indicate the position of an atomic number in the periodic table, so converting those atomic numbers into their respective elements, we find:
>
>  largest circle: As Ge W V Fe
>  second-largest circle: Te Os O I Li
>  second-smallest circle: Cu Ne N Ra Y
>  smallest circle: Og Al Si K H

If we then apply that to the diagram,

> some of it looks like gibberish:
>  [image: the filled in diagram]
>
>  But if you read along the diagonals, going out and then back in, from the start, you get **OCTAGONAL SNOWFLAKE**, which is exactly what this looks like!

Comment: All good  Well done! Also, the title referred to the fact that rot13(bpgntbany fabjsynxrf) don't exist, at least naturally.